# Artefacts in PERSIANN-CCS data

Tags: precipitation, remote-sensing, rainfall, earth-observation

I downloaded [PERSIANN-CCS](http://chrsdata.eng.uci.edu/) for the region of Pawlowdar, Kazakhstan and this has stripes all over my downloaded data.
For another AOI in Kazakhstan I do not have this problem.

Does anyone of you have any idea where these artefacts are coming from?
I did not process the data at all.

[image]

Comment: unfortunately I am not allowed to provide a .kml-file, but with the information given this should be sufficient to reproduce the problem @Jan Doggen

Answer (score 2):

The *Further reading* link brings you to [The PERSIANN System Fine Resolution Precipitation Estimates Using PERSIANN-Cloud Classification System](http://chrs.web.uci.edu/SP_activities01.php) which shows that the data is merged with signals coming from both geostationary and polar/near polar satellites. My guess is that it's just banding in one of these datasets (probably from that second group of satelites).

I tried to look at raw image data from these satellites (to illustrate my assumption), but I bump into sites that are affected by the current US government shutdown, resulting in e.g. incorrect and expired CSS certificates.

If you can dig up these raw images in a later stage, you'll probably be able to map the width of those bands to the aperture of the satellite.

Comment: Thanks a lot for you effort so far @Jan Doggen! that is my guess as well, that i have got the stripes in the data because of poor merging techniques applied. At the moment i am in contact with the provider of the PERSIANN-CCS data. I will keep you informed on updates! /b

Comment: note: when i am just visualising the data on URL:http://chrsdata.eng.uci.edu/ I do not have these stripes.